# Updating values in NSArray that's backing UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

Cocoa, not iOS.  I have an array of items that is backing a UITableview.  I go through the array and perform a series of tasks, specifically, I'm calling an external script executable with NSTask.  While the task is executing, I want to update the "Status" column in the UITableView.

I update the value of the array that's associated to the column, and then call [_TableView reloadData], but No changes in the UI, until all of the processing is done.

```
    for (int ix = 0; ix < [_sceneList count]; ix++) {

        // update status in array backing the TableView        
        [[_sceneList objectAtIndex:ix] setRenderStatus:@"Rendering"];
        [_tableView reloadData];

        // execute command via shell script
        [self runScript:@"run_script.bash":appPath:outputFormat:showGUI:threadCnt:resolution:renderFile:outputFile];

        [[_sceneList objectAtIndex:ix] setRenderStatus:@"Complete"];        
        [_tableView reloadData];
     }
```

code for run_script:

```
-(void) runScript:(NSString*)scriptName:(NSString*)appPath:(NSString*)outputFormat:(NSString*)showGUI:(NSString*)threadCnt:(NSString*)resolution:(NSString*)renderFile:(NSString*)outputFile;  
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    NSArray *arguments;
    NSString* newpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] , scriptName];

    [task setLaunchPath: newpath];

    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appPath, showGUI, renderFile,  outputFile, outputFormat, threadCnt, resolution ,nil];

    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"script returned:\n%@", string);    
}
```

Any ideas why the UI isn't updating?

Is there some sort of "tableview:updateRow" method I should use?

_mike

Comment: Updated post to include code for runScript:

Comment: You claim this is not an iOS question, but you're talking about `UITableView`, which is an iOS-only class. What are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry bout that.  Been doing a lot of iOS work recently.  This is a Cocoa app, so it should be NSTableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something in runScript is running synchronously and blocking your main thread from updating the UI. After reading [this](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?WrappingUnixApps), I think your problem is the

```
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
```

Instead, make this an asynchronous call with:

```
[file readInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

You'll need to subscribe to the notification in the NotificationCenter, probably inside your init method with something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(fileHandleReadCompleted:)
name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification 
object:nil];
```

Then inside your fileHandleReadCompleted: you can use

```
data = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];
```

to retrieve the results.